# How can we pass two agruments in Terraform import script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I need to import an existing order to terraform state.
For example:
Consider I need to pass ID and Environment values to import the script.

if we have to pass only one argument say ID, we can use the below script

> `terraform import hashicups_order.sample {id}`

In my case I need to pass two arguments, we can say it id and environmentValue. So how can we do that?

> `terraform import hashicups_order.sample {id} {one more argument???}`

Comment: What is ` {environment}`? Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: {environment} is an second argument which I need to pass with argument {id}

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TF import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import) has the following form

```
terraform import [options] ADDRESS ID
```

`ADDRESS ID` is a **single value** (not multiple values) uniquely identifying the resource to be imported.

If you wish to pass any other values to `import` you have to use [-var](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import#var-foo-bar) in `[options]` as explained in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import#var-foo-bar).

Comment: Can you provide me an example

Comment: `terraform import -var 'environment_name=test' hashicups_order.sample 123`

Getting this error:

│ Error: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ A variable named "'environment_name" was assigned on the command line, but the root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a "variable" block to the
│ configuration.

Comment: This is a correct answer! I was doing `terraform import "azuread_application.appreg" "000...000" ` and was getting the error above. The problem was `"` sign. If you remove that and instead do `terraform import azuread_application.appreg 0000....0000` then you should not get any errors. It worked for me :)